# Converting Cube Maps

Tags: rendering, cubemap

I have cube maps in lat/long format, and i need to convert them to Horizontal/Vertical Cross, and individual cross images, is there an utility to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your source image is in [equirectangular projection](http://wiki.panotools.org/Equirectangular_Projection). You might try [PTStitcher](http://www.all-in-one.ee/~dersch/), part of the Panorama Tools package. It's designed to be controlled via script files, but there's a batch file located [here](http://www.pinlady.net/vr/#anchor3) called "Pano2Faces.bat" which is designed to simplify the use of PTStitcher to do an equirectangular-to-rectilinear conversion (although it probably won't work out-of-the-box on any version of Windows more recent than XP).

You can probably find a more user-friendly option somewhere on [this page](http://wiki.panotools.org/Extracting_and_inserting_rectilinear_Views).

Comment: Yes, that's what i have.

Answer (score 0):

The tool we use for this is HDR Shop located here. http://ict.debevec.org/~debevec/HDRShop/

Version 1 of it is free. The option to use is "Panoramic Transformation". I can't say that this is the easiest tool to use in the world but its what we do.